# Will I have freedom to operate considering prior art cited by examiner?

Tags: prior-art-request, freedom-to-operate, 3d, scanning

http://www.google.com/patents/US7840300

https://www.behance.net/gallery/4027391/UF-Engineer-Develops-Full-Color-3D-Scanning-Microscope

I call this a "Full Spectrum Lapidary 3D Image Scanner and Method", or a "3D Solid Scanner" for short. It uses polishing techniques vs. mechanical machining using cutting tools as other prior art cited:

[The Crump Group (now Cimquest Inc.)](http://www.cimquest-inc.com/services/iris-scanning-services/)...

[US9324129](https://www.google.com/patents/US9324129)

[WO2009143005A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2009143005A1)

... in particular has marketed a machine tool that creates solid 3D models using milling machines and layer imaging cameras.  Software is used to reassemble the photographed layers into 3D SOLID models.  I have cited prior art that precedes the Crump inventions as well.  How do I determine freedom to operate issues in regard to these facts?

A "child patent" is a patent that derives some of it's novelty from previous work on a particular invention ... is my understanding.

Does anyone know of any other prior art such as the Visible Human Projects that was not referenced by the Crump patents or my patent?

https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/visible/visible_human.html

Comment: I'm afraid I can't quite work out what you're asking. Are you asking about novelty of your own application (since you mention that prior art has been cited). Or are you asking if some prior art is sufficient to invalidate the patent you refer to?

Comment: Very astute.  The logical answer would be both.  I think Crump's work has prior art that could invalidate some if not most of his patents and yet my work which was somewhat taught by Crump but mostly by the prior art that Crump learned from as well (the public domain Visible Human) is quite novel and new because I used lapidary methods and open source software.  I'll clean up my question some more.

Comment: People can read the patents and provide their opinion, but really that will be no assurance of freedom to operate. You can pay a lawyer for an FTO opinion, but again if it gets to court you are at the mercy of judge and jury.

Comment: Eric - I was hoping a legally trained person might chime in.  If not best answer gets the bounty.

Comment: As a legally trained person, I have to reiterate my earlier point that it is rather unclear what you're asking. I have to recommend clearly separating what the patent you are concerned about is, and what the relevant prior art is (and if there are multiple pieces of prior art, setting them out separately). Because at this stage, I simply can't tell which parts of your question pertain to which, and how this Crump Group is involved.

Comment: As an aside, "child patent" isn't really a term I've ever heard used. You might be thinking of divisionals (which are called "continuations" in the US), which are subsequent patent applications that take the priority date of an earlier-filed parent application and relate to matter that was disclosed in the earlier-filed application.

Comment: Thank you Maca ... I appreciate your candor.  I think you are correct in regard to child patent, It may be an informal term.  I'm  just trying to attract more responses like yours.

Comment: Anyone who posts an answer that is up-voted 2 times will automatically receive some of the bounty after the grace period expires ... I will up-vote any cogent answers in the meantime and mark it as answered.  Thank You so much for your inputs!

Comment: Child patent as opposed to parent patent refers to patents of the same family where the child claims (at least partly) priority on the parent. I's this question still relevant, and if yes, do you want to invalidate the Crump patent or know what it covers or both?